# Print all $matches php

Tags: php, foreach

I have the following as a result of a preg_match_all

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => $9.70 [1] => $10 [2] => $11.95 [3] => $0.49 [4] => $2.95 [5] => $2.95 [6] => $2.95 [7] => $2.95 [8] => $0.49 [9] => $9.70 ) )
```

I'm trying to print them all in a foreach loop but getting only first character.

Here's what I'm trying:

```
$i = '0';

foreach ($matches[0] as $val) {
    echo $val[$i].'<br />';
    $i++;
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP `foreach` works a different way than you think. Let me explain this using the following code:

```
$matches = array('One', 'Two', 'Three');
foreach ($matches as $value) {
    // The following code is called once for every array item, and $value is set to that array item
    echo $value . '<br />';
}
```

This code gives the following output:

```
One
Two
Three
```

This happens because the foreach body is called once for every array item, and $value is set to the value of that array item. Using your code one only sees the first character, because PHP allows you to get a single character from a string using array syntax. Long story short, change your code to the following:

```
foreach ($matches[0] as $val) {
    echo $val . '<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

try

```
foreach ($matches[0] as $val) {
    echo $val.'<br />';

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
foreach ($matches[0] as $val) {
    echo $val.'<br />';
}
```

You don't need the `$i` in here as `$val` already contains your array item. If you do `$val[$i]` you are accessing a certain character in the string `$val`.

Answer (score 1):

//it's print all values of $matches array

```
foreach ($matches[0] as $val)
     {
        echo $val.'<br />';

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($matches[0] as $val) {
    echo $val;
}
```